# C# multi pages viewr picturebox

Tags: c#-4.0

i have picture box and I'm loading multi pages documents and i need to make  buttons to page up and page down to show the front page or
 back(down) page any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Image img = Image.FromFile(Variables.collection[imgNo].ToString());
    int pa = img.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

    for (int x = 0; x < pa; x++)
    {
        numpages.Text = pa.ToString();
        current.Text = (pa).ToString();

        int activepage = x + 1;
        img.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, x);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
        pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, x);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```